# C - ODBC - Excel или как считать данные из Excel на чистом C

Tags: c, excel, ado, odbc

**Описание проблемы**

В общем, возникла у меня необходимость вытаскивать данные из *Excel* таблиц, и все бы ничего, но пишу я на чистом *Си* и использование другого языка пока что не допустимо.

Немного погуглив опечалился тем, что все решения расписаны под *C++*, *VB* и *C#*.

Под Си можно использовать *ODBC*, но это приблуда для Баз Данных и все что я нашел - это книжку по *ODBC* с примерами на Си.

---

**Непосредственно вопрос**

Может кто знает или работал/писал на `C - ODBC - Excel` как это реализовать? Или альтернатива *ODBC* (говорят с *ADO* на чистом *Си* все плохо)?

Полезные ссылки приветствуются.

Или вообще альтернатива альтернатив - может можно во что-нибудь конвертить *Excel файлы*, чтобы потом удобно работать с ними из под *Си* (естественно нужно все делать из под программы/не вручную).

Comment: Вижу 3 пути решения проблемы: 1) конвертить XLS в CSV и парсить текстовый файл (утилит хватает) 2) Использовать парсер XLS на каком либо языке, вытаскивать нужные данные в текстовый файл, и его обрабатывать в С-программе 3) Писать свой парсер XLS (ИМХО непросто) 3.5) http://libxls.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую все же использовать ODBC. Это универсальный способ при работе с `Excel`, к тому же, он не требует изобретать велосипеды. Драйверы ODBC для Excel поддерживают SQL синтаксис при обращении к регионам ячеек, типа:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:B10]
```

(более подробную информацию можно получить из аналогичного вопроса с enSO: [Run SQL on excel table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/run-sql-on-excel-table))

Поэтому, если человек знает общий синтаксис и вообще - в теме SQL, проблем с адаптацией к работе в `Excel` будет минимум.

Вам нужно просто найти пошаговые инструкции ODBC с примерами. Предлагаю начать отсюда: [ODBC from C Tutorial Part 1](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html).

Не хотите ODBC API - используйте любой другой ODBC-враппер, с которым Вам будет комфортнее: [1](https://github.com/lexicalunit/nanodbc), [2](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/odbc/article.php/c4337/A-Simple-and-Smart-ODBC-Wrapper-Library.htm), [3](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/a-lightweight-c-wrapper-for-microsofts-o/184416383), ... - (топ в гугле по запросу `odbc wrappers`)

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать библиотеку LibXL (http://www.libxl.com). Она позволит Вам считать данные из таблицы Excel, в т.ч. и на языке C, на нём также дано несколько хороших примеров. Единственный минус - она платная, Вы сможете обработать лишь до 300 ячеек в таблице (однако если Вам этого достаточно, то по-моему идеальный вариант).